# How to parse the json object using jackson in server

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am sending the username, password, mail and phone to the server using ajax post. I want to parse the json data sent in the server. How do i do it?

```
var usname=
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#signup").click(function()
    {
          $.ajax(
          {
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/signup',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
                    uname: document.getElementById("usname").value,
                    pword: document.getElementById("psword").value,
                    mail: document.getElementById("mail").value,
                    phone: document.getElementById("phone").value    
                },    
                success: function (data) {    
                    window.location.href="/";
                },
                error: function(){
                    window.location.href="/";   
                }

            });

      });
});
```

Java code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String signupUser(@RequestParam String uname, @RequestParam String pword,@RequestParam S         
  String mail, @RequestParam String phone,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   
   response,HttpSession session) throws MailException 
{
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Entity uDetails = new Entity("UDetails");

    uDetails.setProperty("userName",uname);
    uDetails.setProperty("passWord", pword);
    uDetails.setProperty("email",mail);
    uDetails.setProperty("phoneNumber",phone);

    datastore.put(uDetails);

    System.out.println("I got printed");

    session.setAttribute("username", uname);
    session.setAttribute("loggedin","yes");

    System.out.println("I got printed too ");
    return "redirect:/";

}
```

Ofcourse, i can do that with request param annotation. But, I have been given an assignment in which i have been specifically asked to parse the json object using the jackson

Comment: So where's your java-code ;)

Comment: OK., will upload right away.,